# Excluding specific category from custom theme functions

Tags: categories

I've currently got some custom theme functions running (custom single product page and java script) although want to exclude a specific category from them. How do I go about this?

I currently have implemented a calculator into my single product using the following script;

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'calc_fun', '/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/assets/js/calc.js', array(), '1.6');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'calc_css', '/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/assets/css/calc.css', true , 9.1 );
}
```

This calculator features on the single product page and works out quantity and m2 of products. This calculator is tied in with a custom single product page using the following scripts;

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_before_addtocart_button_func' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_true_addtocart_button_func');
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_woo_shop_loop_item_title');


function add_content_before_addtocart_button_func() {

        // Echo content.
        get_template_part( 'woo-singlre-product-card', 'template' );

}
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {

        // Echo content.
        get_template_part( 'woo-singlre-product-card-after', 'template' );

}
function add_content_after_true_addtocart_button_func(){
    get_template_part( 'woo-after-single-product', 'template'); 
}

function add_woo_shop_loop_item_title() {
    get_template_part( 'woo-shop-loop-item-title', 'template'); 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_add_product_description');
function custom_add_product_description ($category) {
    get_template_part( 'woo-shop-loop-card-after', 'template' );
}
```

I want to exclude these scripts from the specific category 'example'.

Comment: Do you want the function *not to be performed* if the product belongs to specific categories?

Comment: @nmr And that is correct - I want the function not to be performed on products belonging to a specific category.

Answer (score 0):

WP provides a number of conditionals. So, instead of this, which adds your JS and CSS to every URL on the site

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'calc_fun', '/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/assets/js/calc.js', array(), '1.6');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'calc_css', '/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/assets/css/calc.css', true , 9.1 );
}
```

You will want something like this, which only adds your JS and CSS to certain URLs

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
    // Only enqueue if this is a single product page that's not in product category "example"
    // has_term will accept either the name, term ID, or slug of the product category
    if(is_singular('product') && !has_term('example', 'product_cat')) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'calc_fun', '/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/assets/js/calc.js', array(), '1.6');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'calc_css', '/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/assets/css/calc.css', true , 9.1 );
    }
}
```

You can do the same thing inside your other functions - instead of always doing `get_template_part()`, wrap that inside of a conditional that checks whether this is the specific product you want to add your code to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one category to exclude you can use something like:

```
function se337775_omit_calculator()
{
    global $post;

    // calculator can be added only on single product page
    if ( ! is_singular('product') ) {
        return true;
    }

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    //
    // slugs of categories without calculator
    $excluded = ['first_category', 'another_category'];
    //
    // get current product category
    $product_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'id=>slug' ) );
    if ( ! is_array($product_terms) ) {
        $product_terms = [];
    }
    else {
        $product_terms = array_values( $product_terms );
    }
    //
    // if product has any of category from "$excluded" - return TRUE
    $in_excluded_cat = array_intersect($product_terms, $excluded);
    if ( is_array($in_excluded_cat) && count($in_excluded_cat) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And then use this function where it is needed:

```
function my_scripts_method() {

    if ( se337775_omit_calculator() )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'calc_fun', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/calc.js', array(), '1.6');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'calc_css',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/calc.css', true , 9.1 );
}
```